# .Net core check AD for existing group and create it

Tags: windows, active-directory, .net-core

How do I check in .net core (console app) if a given AD-group already exists ?
And how to create it, if not existing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running your code on Windows as specified in the tags, quite easy. Install [Windows Compatibility Pack nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) and among others you'll get `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` namespace with the classes that are available in classic .NET.

[See this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) for many code samples.